# How to get the text colour of excel cell using xlrd or openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd

Requirement: I want to read an Excel sheet and perform some action on the cells that have the text in red colour. I am using Python and xlrd.

Is there any way to get the font colour of Excel cell using xlrd or openpyxl?

Comment: Please provide some of your code. You cannot expect us to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the spreadsheet using xlrd, be sure to specify `formatting_info=True` to have `xlrd` read the formatting info (I think this may only work for `.xls` files, but I haven't checked).

The [xlrd documentation](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) has details on how to interpret the formatting information for a cell.

Comment: I went thorugh this but this documentation does not have any functionality to get the text colour of the cell.

Comment: It's there, you just have to dig a bit.  Once you have a sheet (open a workbook, get a reference to a sheet), you can use `cell_xf_index(rowx, colx)` to get the `xf` (eXcel Format) index for a cell, which you can use as an index into the workbook `xf_list`.  The XF tells you what font definition is used; font definitions have a color index.  If the color index translates to red, you've found what you want.